# How to break XSLT for-each loop

Tags: xslt

This my xml structure is i want parse the value using for each in run time

```
 <Header> 'Xml Structure start here'
        <DocNumber>743439</DocNumber> 'Document Number'
           <Order>
          <Order>450</Order> '1 st Order Number'
          <OrderDetails>
             <ItemCode>1232954</ItemCode>
            <Qty> 'Quantity;
              72
            </Qty>
              </OrderDetails>
         <OrderDetails>
             <ItemCode>1232955</ItemCode>
            <Qty>
              72
            </Qty>
             </OrderDetails>
    </Order>
    <Order>
          <Order>451</Order> 'Second order number'
          <OrderDetails>
             <ItemCode>1232954</ItemCode>
            <Qty>
              72
            </Qty>
            </OrderDetails>
         <OrderDetails>
             <ItemCode>1232955</ItemCode>
            <Qty> 'Quantity'
              72
            </Qty>                
          </OrderDetails>
    </Order> 'Xml structure finished here'
```

My XSLT:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="Header/Order">
     <xsl:variable name="OrderNo" select="Order"/>
     <xsl:for-each select="Header/Order[order='450']/OrderDetails"> 'Here Order number i want pass in variable value. how i will do it .it's not fixed next time it's change to 451.'
    </xsl:foreach>
 </xsl:foreach>
```

in for each loop i want pass order number using variable. how i will do it .it's not fixed next time it's change to `451`. I tried using variable 
`<xsl:for-each select="Header/Order[order=<xsl:value-of select="$orderNo"/> ]/OrderDetails">`. But it's not working

Comment: It's a bit messy. Can you remove unuseful text in your XML (I guess that 'Second order number' should be comments), and post the full XSLT?

Comment: `<Header> 
        <DocNumber>743439</DocNumber> 
           <Order>
          <Order>450</Order> 
          <OrderDetails>
             <ItemCode>1232954</ItemCode>           
              </OrderDetails>
         <OrderDetails>
             <ItemCode>1232955</ItemCode>
               </OrderDetails>
    </Order>
    <Order>
          <Order>451</Order> 
          <OrderDetails>
             <ItemCode>1232954</ItemCode>
                </OrderDetails>
         <OrderDetails>
             <ItemCode>1232955</ItemCode>                        
          </OrderDetails>
    </Order> `

Comment: Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: It would be far better to add it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that for each `Order` element you are selecting, you want to iterate over the child `OrderDetail` elements.

You don't need to do anything complicated for this, as your nested `xsl:for-each` can contain an xpath expression that is relative to the current node.

```
 <xsl:for-each select="Header/Order">
     Order - <xsl:value-of select="Order" />
     <xsl:for-each select="OrderDetails">
        ItemCode - <xsl:value-of select="ItemCode" />
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:for-each>
```